# MongoDB Server Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, robo3t

I've installed MongoDB on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS and allowed connections through the firewall. When I run the server using the command (mongod), it starts without a problem and I can then connect to it (using RoboMongo as test application).

However, when I run the service automatically on startup (using systemctl), I cannot connect to it. I verified it was running, and could not run it myself as the address was already in use.

Does anyone have any experience with this, or any tips on how to solve the problem? The server will be running localhost only and I'm going to be using an SSH tunnel for testing purposes, so no authentication is necessary.

Anyone?

Comment: If you will be using a tunnel then why did you allow connections through your firewall? That makes no sense

Comment: I didn't explain properly, my apologies. I tested it first without an SSH tunnel, and found out the problem. The problem persists with the SSH tunnel in place. I now removed the exception from the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

When you started mongod did you then provide a configuration file (using the --config or -f parameter)? If not then it defaults to listening on all interfaces.

The default configuration file which is used when starting the daemon with systemctl defaults to only listen on localhost preventing it from being available on the network. This is fine if you intend to connect to the server using a tunnel.

Comment: No, I didn't provide a configuration file, but I didn't think it was necessary as it works perfectly if I start it myself. Judging by your answer, I was right. Do you have any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: mongod uses a default configuration when run without any options. Starting Mongo using systemctl will usually cause it to read a configuration file somewhere (try /etc/mongod.conf). 

How do you create your tunnel?

Comment: Robomongo creates the SSH tunnel for you. I authenticate using username/password. But, what I don't get, is that it should use the same configuration when I run it myself without any configuration file specified, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it should. It would be a good idea if you updated your question with some more information (logfiles would be a good start). Perhaps someone with more knowledge about Robomongo can figure out whats wrong then

Comment: Robomongo isn't the issue, as it works perfectly fine with and without the ssh tunnel as long as I start it with the command. To double test, I also tried it using mongo.exe for Windows, which can connect perfectly fine as long as I run it myself. Looking at the logs, it reports nothing. The error in the console is 

connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Comment: As I said - update your question with more information.